# how to get id from object in POST request

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here I m making a POST request with the following data:

```
{
  "ruleAssignmentDetails": {
    "id": 1,
    "ruleAssignment": {
      "id": 1,
      "empId": 1,
      "roleId": 1,
      "empName": "Emp01",
      "roleName": "CEO"
    },
    "detailSrl": 12,
    "rule": 4,
    "validityType": "F",
    "startDate": "2021-06-14",
    "endDate": null,
    "frequency": {
      "id": 1,
      "frequencyName": "Test",
      "frequencyTpe": "Weekly"
    }
  },
  "detailSrl": 12,
  "parameterName": "Param1",
  "valueType": "D",
  "overwriteValue": null,
  "targetDefination": {
    "id": 1,
    "targetName": "MIN SALES",
    "displayName": "MIN SALES"
  }
}
```

split the objects into respective models but when I m not getting the 'id' of `targetDefination` and `ruleAssignmentDetails`

`serializer.py`

```
class RuleAssignmentParamsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ruleAssignmentDetails = RuleAssignmentDetailsSerializers()
    targetDefination = TargetDefinationSerializers()

    class Meta:
        model = RuleAssignmentParams
        fields = (
            'id',
            'ruleAssignmentDetails',
            'detailSrl',
            'parameterName',
            'valueType',
            'overwriteValue',
            'targetDefination',
        )

    def create(self,validated_data):
        ruleAssDetails = validated_data.pop('ruleAssignmentDetails')
        targetdef = validated_data.pop('targetDefination')
        serial = RuleAssignmentParams.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return serial
```

`views.py`

```
def getSimpleRules(request):
    simpleRules = RuleSimple.objects.all()
    simpleRulesSer = OnlySimpleRules(simpleRules,many=True)
    return JsonResponse(simpleRulesSer.data,safe=False) 

@api_view(['GET'])
def getRuleAssignment(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("get working")
        q=get_object_or_404(RuleAssignmentParams,pk=pk)
        f=RuleAssignmentParamsSerializers(q)
        return JsonResponse(f.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def ruleAssignment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        validated_data = data
        serializer=RuleAssignmentParamsSerializers(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK,safe=False)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

when I run this it shows me this error:

```
IntegrityError at /api/rules/ruleassign
(1048, "Column 'ruleAssignmentDetails_id' cannot be null")
```

How do I get the id of `ruleAssignmentDetails` and `targetDefination` ?

Answer (score 0):

The create method in your serializer looks incorrect. Try this:

```
class RuleAssignmentParamsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ruleAssignmentDetails = RuleAssignmentDetailsSerializers()
    targetDefination = TargetDefinationSerializers()

    class Meta:
        model = RuleAssignmentParams
        fields = (
            'id',
            'ruleAssignmentDetails',
            'detailSrl',
            'parameterName',
            'valueType',
            'overwriteValue',
            'targetDefination',
        )

    def create(self,validated_data):
        ruleAssDetails = validated_data.pop('ruleAssignmentDetails')
        targetdef = validated_data.pop('targetDefination')
        rule_serial = RuleAssignmentDetailsSerializers() 
        rule_instances = rule_serial.create(ruleAssDetails)
        target_serial = RuleAssignmentDetailsSerializers() 
        target_instances = rule_serial.create(targetdef) 
        serial = RuleAssignmentParams.objects.create(**validated_data)
        
        instance = super(RuleAssignmentParams, self).create(validated_data)
        instance.ruleAssignmentDetails.add(*rule_instances)
        instance.ruleAssignmentDetails.add(*target_instances)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Only works if the the ForeignKey in your model is not required. (***blank=True, null=True***). Otherwise you have to your ***rule_id*** and ***target_id*** to your ***validated_data***.